# collections_for_select always return `wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)`

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I know this issue was a simple, but I can't solve yet. Probably you guys have sharper eyes than me.

I have `select_tag` which:

```
<%= f.select :product_type, options_for_select([["Raw Material", "0"], ["Semi Material", "1"], ["Finish", "2"]], @product.product_type,), { :prompt => "Select Product Type" }, :required => true %>
```

a simple `select_tag` but it always return `wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)`

I try to copy paste from my other `select_tag` that very similar like this one and had work perfect on it's page, but still return that error on this page.

I try to break the code to be:

```
33. <%= f.select :product_type, options_for_select([["Raw Material", "0"],
34. ["Semi Material", "1"],
35. ["Finish", "2"]], 
36. @product.product_type,
37. ), { :prompt => "Select Product Type" }, :required => true %>
```

And it return error on the row `36`.

I don't know why make this not working. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It my mistake on my model that I created an procedure that have same name on the field. So that's why it always return error cause on my model `def product_type(id)`

Really sorry and thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could try removing the trailing comma at the end of line 36.

Comment: No sir, it still the same, but sorry, it my mistake on my model. Ill answer for my self. Thank you anw